# Same instance variable for all actions of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, instance-variables

I have a rails controller with two actions defined: `index` and `show`.
I have an instance variable defined in `index` action. The code is something like below:

```
def index
  @some_instance_variable = foo
end

def show
  # some code
end
```

How can I access the `@some_instance_variable` in `show.html.erb` template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you're rendering `show.html.erb` from the `index` action, you'll need to set `@some_instance_variable` in the show action as well. When a controller action is invoked, it calls the matching method -- so the contents of your `index` method will not be called when using the `show` action.

If you need `@some_instance_variable` set to the same thing in both the `index` and `show` actions, the correct way  would be to define another method, called by both `index` and `show`, that sets the instance variable.

```
def index
  set_up_instance_variable
end

def show
  set_up_instance_variable
end

private

def set_up_instance_variable
  @some_instance_variable = foo
end
```

Making the `set_up_instance_variable` method private prevents it from being called as a controller action if you have wildcard routes (i.e., `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`)

Comment: Thanks @Emily. But is there a DRY-er way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks @Emily i was looking for the same. Cheers!

Comment: Just add `before_action :set_up_instance_variable, only: [:show, :index]` to the controller. That will run `set_up_instance_variable` before whichever actions you specify.

Answer (score 59):

You can define instance variables for multiple actions by using a before filter, e.g.:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :common_content, :only => [:index, :show]

  def common_content
    @some_instance_variable = :foo
  end
end
```

Now `@some_instance_variable` will be accessible from all templates (including partials) rendered from the `index` or `show` actions.

Comment: @Mori How would you go about deciding whether to place the method/object in private or protected or public space? Thks!

Comment: Just for future readers. DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead.