# Rails4 How to define variable values in before_filter or private action when define in other UI process method?

Tags: variables, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I posted a question on how to share variables across actions in same controller.  I found this Q/A that answered my question mostly but still left a pending question raised in this submission.
Here is the link for the Q/A I found that might help someone else: [Same instance variable for all actions of a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330486/same-instance-variable-for-all-actions-of-a-controller)

Here is the link for my initial question which I answered with the link above: [In Rails4 How to assign variables in one controller action and use the value of it in another controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291574/in-rails4-how-to-assign-variables-in-one-controller-action-and-use-the-value-of)

Now that I know I can use the before_filter and create a private action that can then be referenced from the various actions in the controller which appears to be great for known constant variables, how do I set it up in my specific case where the values change based on user action and are defined 
in the user interactive action?

I have a method called 'evaluate_media'.  This method allows the user to select a file from various directory paths and then runs media info on the selected video file and parses the xml for certain attributes (like bitrate, aspect_ratio) and assigns the values to variables in the action.  Is there any way I can share the looked up and assigned variables in this action with the other actions like the common_components without it being private and just for variable assignment?   Can you please show me an example of how to do this?  I did try the before_filter as so and it doesn't even call the insert. It just refreshes the page. 
before_filter :evaluate_media, :only => [:save_file]

Just as a refresher from my first question, After I gather this information in my evaluate_media action, I have a save button that calls the save_file method that will store this information gathered in the evaluate_media action.

Here are the 2 defined methods:

```
def save_file    

        src_location = @radio_button_value
        directory = "#{@dir_path_choice}"
        full_path = @filepathname
        full_filename = "#{@filepath}"
        alias_code = "#{@file_alias}"
        validate_status = "#{@file_status}" 
        error_msg = "#{@file_msg}"
        video_alias_match = "#{@msg_dtl1}" 
        audio_alias_match = "#{@msg_dtl2}" 
        video_format = "#{@video_format}" 
        video_bitrate = "#{@video_bitrate}" 
        video_width = "#{@video_width}"
        video_height = "#{@video_height}" 
        video_framerate = "#{@video_framerate}" 
        video_aspect_ratio = "#{@video_aspectratio}" 
        video_scan_type = "#{@video_scantype}"
        video_scan_order = "#{@video_scanorder}" 

        @file_alias_tfile = FileAliasTfile.new( :src_location => src_location, :directory => directory, :full_path => full_path, :full_filename => full_filename, :file_ext => '', 
                                                      :assigned_status => 'Unassigned', :file_status => 'Saved', :alias_code => alias_code, :validate_status => validate_status, :error_msg => error_msg, 
                                                      :video_alias_match => video_alias_match, :audio_alias_match => audio_alias_match, :video_format => video_format, :video_bitrate => video_bitrate, 
                                                      :video_width => video_width, :video_height => video_height, :video_framerate => video_framerate, :video_aspect_ratio => video_aspect_ratio, 
                                                      :video_scan_type => video_scan_type, :video_scan_order => video_scan_order, :video_alias_code => '', :audio_alias_code => '', 
                                                      :bus_prod_initiative_id => 0, :status => 'Active', :start_date => DateTime.now.to_date, :end_date => '', :deleted_b => 0, 
                                                      :created_by => 'admin', :updated_by => 'admin')


    if @file_alias_tfile.save
      redirect_to mainpages_home_path, :notice => "The file alias validation has been saved."
    else
      redirect_to alias_mainpages_home_path, :notice => "The file alias validation has not been saved."
    end
  end
```

---

```
 def evaluate_media

     @state = 'post'
     @radio_button_value = params[:location]

     @stored_file = FileAliasTfile.where(:full_path => params[:filepath2], :deleted_b => 0).first

     if @stored_file.present?
        @file_exists_flag = 'Y'
        @file_exists_msg = 'This File and Alias has been saved in application.'
     else
        @file_exists_flag = 'N'
        @file_exists_msg = 'This File and Alias has NOT been saved in application yet.'
      end

          root_dir = '/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/'
          provider_dir = ""

       @selected_filepath = params[:filepath2]
       @filepath = params[:filepath2]

       @media_xml = ::MediaInfo.call(@filepath)  
       @alias_xml = ::AliasGenerator.call(@media_xml)

       @media_xml_for = ""
       @alias_xml_for = ""
       REXML::Document.new(@media_xml).write(@media_xml_for, 1)
       REXML::Document.new(@alias_xml).write(@alias_xml_for, 1)
       alias_parse_doc = ""
       media_parse_doc = ""
       alias_parse_doc = REXML::Document.new(@alias_xml)  
       media_parse_doc = REXML::Document.new(@media_xml) 


       #parse Alias XML Doc   
       @aliasgen_ver = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "/aliasGenerator vr=/text()") { |element| element }    
       @file_alias = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//alias/text()") { |element| element }
       @file_status = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//error/text()") { |element| element }
       @file_msg = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//error_m/text()") { |element| element }
       @msg_dtl1 = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//closestvideoalias/text()") { |element| element }
       @msg_dtl2 = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//closestaudioalias/text()") { |element| element }

       #parse Video Media Info XML Doc  
        @filepathname = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "*//Complete_name/text()") { |element| element }  
        @video_format = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Format/text()") { |element| element }
        @video_bitrate = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Bit_rate/text()") { |element| element }  
        @video_width = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Width/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_height = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Height/text()") { |element| element }
        @video_aspectratio = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Display_aspect_ratio/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_framerate = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Frame_rate/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_scantype = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Scan_type/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_scanorder = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Scan_order/text()") { |element| element }   

       render :action => :index
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I set it up in my specific case where the values change based
>   on user action and are defined in the user interactive action?

If you do the same calculation in more than one action, and the only thing that changes is some value used in the calculation, then instead of having to write essentially the same code in two or more actions you can create a method that does the calculation:

```
def do_calculation(val1, val2)
  #Use val1 and val2 to perform some calculation
  result
end
```

If you put that method in your controller, then the method can be called inside any action. The reason you make the method private is so that no route can hit that method.  Because no route can hit that method, the method is not called an action--it's just called a helper method.  Here is what that would look like:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @files = do_calculations(params[:a], params[:b])
  end

  def show
    @files = do_calculation(params[:b], params[:c])
  end

  private
    def do_calculation(val1, val2)
      #Use val1 and val2 to perform some calculation...
      result
    end 

end
```

Rails 4 has a more complicated way of doing the same thing--it involves putting the helper method in another file.  In your app/controller/ directory, there is a directory called concerns/, and you can do this:

app/controllers/concerns/file_methods.rb:

```
module FileMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def do_calculation(x, y)
    x*y
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you do this:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include FileMethods

  #Then you can call do_calculation() in any of the actions

end
```

If you do it that way, other controllers can include the FileMethods module, too, so that way is more flexible.  In addition, there are other things you can do inside the FileMethods module due to the fact that it extends ActiveSupport::Concern.

> Is there any way I can share the looked up and assigned variables in
>   this action with the other actions...without it being private?

If you are saying that your calculation requires user input, and therefore a `before_filter(Rails3)/before_action(Rails4)` won't work, AND you only want to do the calculation once, then here's the deal.  The web is *stateless*, which means that every request begins as if it were the first request that has EVER been sent over the internet.  *Stateless* means that no state, i.e. variables, are shared with subsequent requests.  In other words, once the server has finished processing a request, it deletes everything related to that request.  So when your browser asks, "Mr. Server, can you please retrieve the value in the previous request and use it in this request?", the server responds, "I'm sorry I have no idea what you are talking about.  I have a severe case of amnesia, and for that I apologize, but as far as I can remember, you have never made a request to me before.  Let me check my records....no, nothing here.  Sorry, no values to retrieve.  Goodbye.  Come again, anytime."

The way that statelessness works in rails is that for every request, rails creates an instance of your controller, e.g. `inst = YourController.new`, then rails calls `inst.actionA`, which creates the @variables specified inside actionA, and the @variables themselves to inst.  Then the views are executed using inst, which makes inst's @variables available in the views.  And for a subsequent request, rails does `inst = YourController.new` then `inst.actionB`.  As a result, the first instance of your controller gets erased along with the @variables that attached themselves to the instance.

However, the stateless nature of the internet has proved inconvenient for web programmers, so various schemes have been invented to make variables persist across requests.  Have you ever heard of cookies?  Cookies are used to store small pieces of data on a user's computer, and then a subsequent request returns that data to the server, so it's *as if* the value persisted on the server between requests.  There is a more refined scheme called *sessions*, which allows you to do the same thing.  With sessions in rails, rails automatically takes care of setting the cookies on the user's computer for you.  All you do is treat an object named `session`, which rails automatically creates for you, as if it were a Hash.  If you set a key/value pair on the `session` object in one action(i.e for one request), then it can be looked up in the session object in another action(i.e. for another request).

Here is an example:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  def action1
    val1 = params[:val1]
    val2 = params[:val2]

    #Use the user input to produce some data:
    dir_list = .........val1......val2.....

    session[:dir_list] = dir_list
  end

  def action2
    @dir_list = session[:dir_list] 
  end

end
```

However...based on your latest flurry of questions, you might want to take a look at the answers to your previous questions--starting with your ajax question.  You might find the answer to that question solves a lot of the problems you are trying to deal with now.