# ruby instace variable scope in homecontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have class HomeController

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def event_one
    Req = **endpoint.connection**
    res = req.body**(json format)**  
    @events = res       
  end
  def event_two
    @events
  end
end
```

Can i use one instance variable(@events) which got response from endpoint in event_one method,from another event_two method.

Comment: do you want to use response from `event_one` into `event_two` ?

Comment: What do you mean with ** ?

Answer (score 2):

try using this DRY code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_events, only: [:event_one, :event_two]

  def event_one
    #your code here
    # for example puts @events
  end

  def event_two
    #your code here
    # for example puts @events        
  end

  private 

  def set_events
    req = **endpoint.connection**
    res = req.body**(json format)**  
    @events = res       
  end

end
```

Comment: @GB I thing you have error in your code. bcs. this before_action: :set_events, only: [:event_one, :event_two] returns syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: @LukasBaliak now see the edit. yes there was error. now removed

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve use a private method to set evnets

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def event_one
    set_events
  end
  def event_two
    set_events
  end
private 

def set_events
    Req = **endpoint.connection**
    res = req.body**(json format)**  
    @events = res       
end

end
```

You can also call this method using filter of you want to set for every action of this controller.

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks, but i want to reduce my execution time. i don't want to read the endpoint connection lines again and again.

Comment: You can only call this method where it is needed 
same kind of question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330486/same-instance-variable-for-all-actions-of-a-controller